# How to efficiently fetch an earlier row that is unique through two attributes?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerpivot, powerbi

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973744/find-rows-relative-to-current-rows-value-in-excel-dax/26995284#26995284), I asked about how we can fetch a simple previous row through an incremented ID field (Thank you Petr Havlík). In this case I have ID and ACTIVITY, where (ACTIVITY&ID) is the unique value per row.

From an SQL perspective I just do an inner join where ACTIVITY = Joined ACTIVITY and ID = ID - 1 in the joined table and get the row I need.

In other words, I want the previous percentage belonging to the same activity.

So using the answer in the previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973744/find-rows-relative-to-current-rows-value-in-excel-dax/26995284#26995284) I was able to get the result I want on 1000 rows. However if I were to increase this number of rows to 85000+ this function is dauntingly slow.

=SUMX(FILTER ( Query, (EARLIER ( [ID] ) = [ID] + 1)&&(EARLIER([ACTIVITY])=[ACTIVITY])),[PERCENTAGE])

My end result is to make this function on up to 7 million rows, if this is possible, how I can optimize it ? And if it isn't, could you explain to me why I can't do it ?

[image: Fetching previous rows with the same ID and Activity]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be to try a variation on the approach - without your dataset I can't test whether it is more efficient but I've run similar things on 1m+ row datasets without issue:

```
=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( [PERCENTAGE] ),
    FILTER (
        Query,
        [ID] = EARLIER ( [ID] ) - 1
        && [ACTIVITY] = EARLIER ( [ACTIVITY] )
    )
)
```

Probably not what you want to hear but doing this with SQL on import is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer here would be using Lookupvalue, that would bypass any filters you need to do and allows you to do a direct lookup of values in the table. This would be much faster.

It would look something like:

```
=LOOKUPVALUE(table[PERCENTAGE], [ID] = EARLIER ( [ID] ) - 1)
```

Please make sure the ID values are unique as lookupvalue can only return a single result, when more than one rows are returned it will error out. You can potentially wrap it around with iserror

```
= IF(ISERROR(LOOKUPVALUE(table[PERCENTAGE], [ID] = EARLIER ( [ID] ) - 1)), BLANK()
           , LOOKUPVALUE(table[PERCENTAGE], [ID] = EARLIER ( [ID] ) - 1)
            )
     )
```

Comment: Kasper, great to see you on here! Absolutely bow to your superior knowledge here although in this case on a similarly sized data set both options are basically too quick to notice a substantive difference. That said my PC is a beast :-) Will be giving your technique a go in the future!

Comment: Kasper, nice to see you here :-)

Answer (score 2):

**JShmay**,

this is pretty much the same question - and as Jacob has suggested, you can use [logical operators](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/757.powerpivot-dax-operator-reference.aspx#Logical_Operators) that are normally available in Excel/PowerPivot.

You can really go crazy with this and should you need something more complex - for example to get difference between two points following some other condition, I would point you to very similar questions and my answers to them:

- [Can I compare values in the same column in adjacent rows in PowerPivot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111109/can-i-compare-values-in-the-same-column-in-adjacent-rows-in-powerpivot/26267866#26267866)
- [2nd latest Date - DAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367911/2nd-latest-date-dax/26392890#26392890)

Hope this helps :)